# Coffee time rebus riddle

Tags: rebus

Given the first picture as context, what does the second picture suggest?

[image]

Comment: Coffee on Wheels!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If not the beautiful suggestion of coffee on wheels, perhaps

> **roller coaster**, because the mug coasters look like they're rolling

Answer (score 14):

Looks like

> a **ROLLER-COASTER**

to me.

Comment: Absolutely ninja'd. 5 seconds.

Comment: Ha, well played!

Comment: Sorry, I could only accept one answer, so I went for @anodyne’s one; in addition to being posted 5 seconds faster it includes a brief description.

Comment: I actually thought @mbingo beat me by 5 seconds but now I see the question was last answered by him so now I'm not sure what to believe. Thanks for the check either way. These puzzles are fun